# How to make the Rules module perform a redirect to an URL that includes a query string?

Tags: 7, rules, redirection

I have created ***Task*** nodes, and I want to redirect to the previous (source) page after creation of a new task. I don't want people to see the task node. That page includes a view of all tasks.

For that I have created a simple rule:

- Event: After saving new content
- Condition: Content is of type tasks
- Actions: Page redirect to `[site:current-page:url]`

This works, but not for a page that includes a query string. The rules redirect action chops off the query string of the source page.

In my case, I have a source page that always includes `?og_group_ref=[node:og-group-ref]` in the URL in order to create group tasks. After creating a group tasks, the redirect happens but the query string in the URL is gone.

I tried to change the Rules redirect using Rules Action "*Page redirect to `[site:current-page:url]?og_group_ref=[node:og-group-ref]`*". However, that gives an error:

> Input evaluation generated an invalid URI.

Is there a way to accomplish [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) redirect including the query string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try the "[Rules URL argument](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_url_argument)" module to get this to work. Here is a quote about it (from its project page):

> ... provides two rules conditions based on URL arguments:
>
> - check if a URL argument is present.
> - compare the value of an URL argument.
>
> It also provides an action that makes the value of an URL argument available as new variable to Rules.

Refer to my answer to "[How to use the Rules module to implement a custom redirect for an outdated URL?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/170742/how-to-use-the-rules-module-to-implement-a-custom-redirect-for-an-outdated-url/170745#170745)" for way more details about this module also.